# How to Remove shadow from Binary Image?

Tags: android, opencv, image-processing

I am doing marker detection using OpenCV in android. I am able to detect the marker using a mobile phone camera. I am using these methods for binary conversion and contour detection:

```
Imgproc.threshold(mTempGray, mBinary,60, 255,Imgproc.THRESH_BINARY|Imgproc.THRESH_OTSU);
Imgproc.findContours(mBinary,contours,ContourMat,Imgproc.RETR_CCOMP,Imgproc.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE);
```

But the problem is when I keep the mobile camera on top of the marker, the thresholding of the image is affected by the shadow so in the contour detection part, I am not able to find out the required contour.
If I scan the marker in positions other than the top, then it works fine.
How do I remove this shadow effect?

Comment: try adaptive threshold.

Comment: Maybe you should try another approach, such as edge detection ? Do you have a pic of your marker, that may help us help you ;)

Comment: yes this is the link http://imgur.com/pOlsuYn&GKkv6X8&FRW0KSA#1

Comment: A bilateral filter preprocess would help : http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/filtering.html?highlight=bilateralfilter#bilateralfilter